# Как ограничить позиционирование контента в зависимости от содержимого то есть его высотой?

Tags: jquery

В этом примере имитируется скролл, изменением его позиционирования?
   как ограничить его в пределах высоты блока чтобы не скролить бесконечно вверх и вниз?

```js
 $('body').on('click','.to-top',function(){
     
     divLocation = $('.overview').offset();
     
     $('.overview').animate({
           'top': divLocation.top + 400
     }, 500);
 })
 $('body').on('click','.to-bottom',function(){
     
     divLocation = $('.overview').offset();
         
         $('.overview').animate({
               'top': divLocation.top - 400
              
         }, 500);
 })
```

```css
.overview {
  height: 2000px; 
  background: #00ffd2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.to-top {
  position: fixed; 
  top:26%; 
  right: 0;
}
.to-bottom {
  position: fixed; 
  top:35%; 
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="overview">
<button class="to-top">вверх</button>
<button class="to-bottom">вниз</button>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ex illum gloriatur has, qui graeci corpora splendide ex, no alienum reprehendunt sed. Sit ut utamur admodum, ei eam nonumes salutatus similique, tota posse eripuit eos no. Quo te atqui graece. Magna quodsi neglegentur cu has, eos eu oratio ancillae, hendrerit contentiones nec no. Ad adhuc recusabo has. Ei vel legere copiosae.

Eros facilisi consectetuer ut sed, in vel albucius detraxit petentium. Eum ne laudem honestatis, no etiam audiam pericula cum. Sit in erat iuvaret pertinacia. Ex virtute interesset pri, eu postea concludaturque vis. Omnis cetero gubergren has ne, ad duo novum exerci labitur. Ea pri enim veri libris.

Atqui liber utamur et mea, nec at modus detraxit. Sed ut sumo oportere explicari, verear offendit voluptaria ut eam. Duo no wisi sensibus, aperiri deleniti principes eu sed. At eam suas tollit.

Veniam fastidii ne cum. Ea idque forensibus sed. Eu mei facer nulla, cu vis quod commodo efficiantur, nec cu erat ridens probatus. Pro liber veritus ocurreret an, nonumy graeco usu ei.

Has ea reque dolorum comprehensam, sea modo mundi placerat ei, in usu clita accusata. Ea verear viderer has, ad nec etiam nulla appellantur, vim utinam animal pericula ei. Sit appetere cotidieque in. Ex vis appareat pertinacia expetendis. Sea id munere aliquam inermis. Sea clita euismod at, nec nobis mediocrem cotidieque eu.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ex illum gloriatur has, qui graeci corpora splendide ex, no alienum reprehendunt sed. Sit ut utamur admodum, ei eam nonumes salutatus similique, tota posse eripuit eos no. Quo te atqui graece. Magna quodsi neglegentur cu has, eos eu oratio ancillae, hendrerit contentiones nec no. Ad adhuc recusabo has. Ei vel legere copiosae.

Eros facilisi consectetuer ut sed, in vel albucius detraxit petentium. Eum ne laudem honestatis, no etiam audiam pericula cum. Sit in erat iuvaret pertinacia. Ex virtute interesset pri, eu postea concludaturque vis. Omnis cetero gubergren has ne, ad duo novum exerci labitur. Ea pri enim veri libris.

Atqui liber utamur et mea, nec at modus detraxit. Sed ut sumo oportere explicari, verear offendit voluptaria ut eam. Duo no wisi sensibus, aperiri deleniti principes eu sed. At eam suas tollit.

Veniam fastidii ne cum. Ea idque forensibus sed. Eu mei facer nulla, cu vis quod commodo efficiantur, nec cu erat ridens probatus. Pro liber veritus ocurreret an, nonumy graeco usu ei.

Has ea reque dolorum comprehensam, sea modo mundi placerat ei, in usu clita accusata. Ea verear viderer has, ad nec etiam nulla appellantur, vim utinam animal pericula ei. Sit appetere cotidieque in. Ex vis appareat pertinacia expetendis. Sea id munere aliquam inermis. Sea clita euismod at, nec nobis mediocrem cotidieque eu.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ex illum gloriatur has, qui graeci corpora splendide ex, no alienum reprehendunt sed. Sit ut utamur admodum, ei eam nonumes salutatus similique, tota posse eripuit eos no. Quo te atqui graece. Magna quodsi neglegentur cu has, eos eu oratio ancillae, hendrerit contentiones nec no. Ad adhuc recusabo has. Ei vel legere copiosae.

Eros facilisi consectetuer ut sed, in vel albucius detraxit petentium. Eum ne laudem honestatis, no etiam audiam pericula cum. Sit in erat iuvaret pertinacia. Ex virtute interesset pri, eu postea concludaturque vis. Omnis cetero gubergren has ne, ad duo novum exerci labitur. Ea pri enim veri libris.

Atqui liber utamur et mea, nec at modus detraxit. Sed ut sumo oportere explicari, verear offendit voluptaria ut eam. Duo no wisi sensibus, aperiri deleniti principes eu sed. At eam suas tollit.

Veniam fastidii ne cum. Ea idque forensibus sed. Eu mei facer nulla, cu vis quod commodo efficiantur, nec cu erat ridens probatus. Pro liber veritus ocurreret an, nonumy graeco usu ei.

Has ea reque dolorum comprehensam, sea modo mundi placerat ei, in usu clita accusata. Ea verear viderer has, ad nec etiam nulla appellantur, vim utinam animal pericula ei. Sit appetere cotidieque in. Ex vis appareat pertinacia expetendis. Sea id munere aliquam inermis. Sea clita euismod at, nec nobis mediocrem cotidieque eu.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ex illum gloriatur has, qui graeci corpora splendide ex, no alienum reprehendunt sed. Sit ut utamur admodum, ei eam nonumes salutatus similique, tota posse eripuit eos no. Quo te atqui graece. Magna quodsi neglegentur cu has, eos eu oratio ancillae, hendrerit contentiones nec no. Ad adhuc recusabo has. Ei vel legere copiosae.

Eros facilisi consectetuer ut sed, in vel albucius detraxit petentium. Eum ne laudem honestatis, no etiam audiam pericula cum. Sit in erat iuvaret pertinacia. Ex virtute interesset pri, eu postea concludaturque vis. Omnis cetero gubergren has ne, ad duo novum exerci labitur. Ea pri enim veri libris.

Atqui liber utamur et mea, nec at modus detraxit. Sed ut sumo oportere explicari, verear offendit voluptaria ut eam. Duo no wisi sensibus, aperiri deleniti principes eu sed. At eam suas tollit.

Veniam fastidii ne cum. Ea idque forensibus sed. Eu mei facer nulla, cu vis quod commodo efficiantur, nec cu erat ridens probatus. Pro liber veritus ocurreret an, nonumy graeco usu ei.

Has ea reque dolorum comprehensam, sea modo mundi placerat ei, in usu clita accusata. Ea verear viderer has, ad nec etiam nulla appellantur, vim utinam animal pericula ei. Sit appetere cotidieque in. Ex vis appareat pertinacia expetendis. Sea id munere aliquam inermis. Sea clita euismod at, nec nobis mediocrem cotidieque eu.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ex illum gloriatur has, qui graeci corpora splendide ex, no alienum reprehendunt sed. Sit ut utamur admodum, ei eam nonumes salutatus similique, tota posse eripuit eos no. Quo te atqui graece. Magna quodsi neglegentur cu has, eos eu oratio ancillae, hendrerit contentiones nec no. Ad adhuc recusabo has. Ei vel legere copiosae.

Eros facilisi consectetuer ut sed, in vel albucius detraxit petentium. Eum ne laudem honestatis, no etiam audiam pericula cum. Sit in erat iuvaret pertinacia. Ex virtute interesset pri, eu postea concludaturque vis. Omnis cetero gubergren has ne, ad duo novum exerci labitur. Ea pri enim veri libris.

Atqui liber utamur et mea, nec at modus detraxit. Sed ut sumo oportere explicari, verear offendit voluptaria ut eam. Duo no wisi sensibus, aperiri deleniti principes eu sed. At eam suas tollit.

Veniam fastidii ne cum. Ea idque forensibus sed. Eu mei facer nulla, cu vis quod commodo efficiantur, nec cu erat ridens probatus. Pro liber veritus ocurreret an, nonumy graeco usu ei.

Has ea reque dolorum comprehensam, sea modo mundi placerat ei, in usu clita accusata. Ea verear viderer has, ad nec etiam nulla appellantur, vim utinam animal pericula ei. Sit appetere cotidieque in. Ex vis appareat pertinacia expetendis. Sea id munere aliquam inermis. Sea clita euismod at, nec nobis mediocrem cotidieque eu.
</div>
```